# A table that displays all the user submitted in the form in the tabular format. But the code does not work properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs

ANGULAR JS CODE:
The below example has been updated by adding a table that displays all the user submitted in the form in the tabular format. But the code does not work properly. Read the code thoroughly and make the necessary changes to make it execute properly.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="addRow()"> 
        First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lastName"><br> 
        Submit: <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form> 
    <p> Full Name: {{fullName()}}</p> 
    <div ng-controller="tableCtrl"
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <th>First Name</th> 
                <th>Last Name</th> 
            </tr> 
            <tr ng-repeat="x in records"> 
                <td>{{x.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{x.lastName}}</td>
            </tr> 
        </table> 
    </div> 
<script> 
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 
        $scope.firstName = myForm.fname.value; 
        $scope.lastName = myForm.lname.value; 
        $scope.fullName = function() { 
            return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName; 
        }; 
    });
    app.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        $scope.records = []; 
        $scope.addRow = function() { 
            $scope.records.push({ 
                'firstName': $scope.firstName, 
                'lastName': $scope.lastName 
            }); 
        };
    }]); 
    </script>
```